# Асинхронный запуск не асинхронного метода

Tags: c#, async-await

Нужно записать в файл, использую метод File.WriteAllText
Правильно ли будет сделать это так для асинхронности?

```
await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(path_json, json));
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllTextAsync`?

Comment: @tym32167
А почему у меня нет такого метода?

Comment: не пишите код под древние фреймворки времен Билла Гейтса, и все методы будут :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С одной стороны да, с другой зависит от того, какая версия .NET используется.

Дело в том, что до релиза .NET 6 асинхронное файловое API было забаговано и было полу-синхронным, то есть блокировало на короткое время вызывающий поток даже при вызове асинхронных методов `File.*****Async()`.

Файловое API переработано и эта проблема исправлена начиная с .NET 6.

Так что для .NET 6 и будущих версий дотнета делайте так:

```
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path_json, json);
```

Для .NET 5 и старше вот так:

```
await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(path_json, json));
```

К тому же в очень старых .NET Framework 4.x `File.WriteAllTextAsync` в принципе отсутствует, так что там альтернатив нет.